# FP action on the expression

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, common-lisp

my question is in reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807629/handling-incremental-data-modeling-changes-in-functional-programming?rq=1), specifically:

```
data Actions a = Actions {
    actEval :: a,
    actMap  :: (a -> a) -> Actions a }
```

I am confused by the recursive defintion of `actMap` function in that it returns a reference to `Actions`, recursively, ie what is the base case for recursion, since there's no type specified for `a`?

How would `Actions` structure be represented in Common Lisp??

**EDIT:** Also, `Actions` constructor takes 2 arguments (as mentioned in the original post). Then what is `Actions a`, as returned by the `actMap`??

Comment: what do you mean by "since there's no type specified for `a`"? Haskell is lazily evaluated so you can have recursive structures with no "base case", like `data Infinite = Next Infinte`

Comment: You seem to be confusing type declarations with data of that type, which makes it hard to tell what your intended question is.

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't confuse type constructor with data constructor.

```
data Actions a = ..
```

here `Actions` is a type constructor. It takes a type `a` and gives a type `Actions a` whereas

```
data Actions a = Actions ..
```

The second `Actions` is a data constructor. So to construct a value of type `Actions a` you need to use data constructor `Actions` with two values, one of type `a` and other of type `(a -> a) -> Actions a`.

The definition of `Actions` is recursive in terms of type, it doesn't mean you need to have a base case for it. You can construct a value of the above type as

```
construct :: a -> Actions a
construct v = Actions v (\fn -> construct $ fn v)
```

It is a valid construction as the first value to the data constructor is of type `a` and the other is a function of the above specified type.

Comment: how would Actions be represented in lisp??? Something like this ??? (defun actEval (a) a)
(defun actMap (f a) '(f (Actions a)))
(defun Actions (arg1 arg2) (list((actEval arg1) (actMap arg2 arg1))) )

Comment: @M.Savchenko I don't know lisp so I can not tell.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Lisp it can be represented just as a structure:

```
(defstruct act eval map)
```

And to follow-up on the mentioned post, you would use it somewhat like this:

```
(defun mk-lit (x)
  (make-act :eval x
            :map (lambda (f) (mk-lit (funcall f x)))))

(defun mk-sum (x y)
  (make-act :eval (+ (act-eval x) (act-eval y))
            :map (lambda (f)
                   (mk-sum (funcall (act-map x) f)
                           (funcall (act-map y) f)))))

CL-USER> (mk-sum (mk-lit 1) (mk-lit 2))
#S(ACT :EVAL 3 :MAP #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA # :IN MK-SUM) {100471902B}>)

CL-USER> (funcall (act-map (mk-sum (mk-lit 1) (mk-lit 2)))
                  #'print)
1 
2 
#S(ACT :EVAL 3 :MAP #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA # :IN MK-SUM) {1007E476FB}>)
```

EDIT: But it's definitely not the most optimal way to deal with such problem in Lisp - there're much simpler and powerful approaches.

Answer (score 0):

As @Satvik mentioned, don't confuse the data type with its constructor. The definition could be changed to

```
data Actions a = ActionsConstructor {
    actEval :: a,
    actMap  :: (a -> a) -> Actions a }
```

which makes a better distinction between the two concepts.

This is a standard [recursive data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type). This is quite similar to lists, for example:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons { head :: a, tail :: List a }
```

only in the case of `Actions`, the structure is potentially infinite - you can always pass another function to `actMap` to get another action, while a list can be terminated by `Nil` at some place.